# Cannot $filter array by reference Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

just a quick Question!

I have an ordering function, which is supposed to order two arrays depending on the situation. So i pass the array reference, but the array is not filtered! Any ideas?

```
function order(rowName, array) {
    if (vm.row === rowName) {
        return;
    }

    vm.row = rowName;
    array = $filter('orderBy')(array, rowName);
    return vm.onOrderChange();
};
```

which is called in my html as :

```
data-ng-click = "vm.order('amount', vm.itemsNew)"
```

i got it working like below, but... well, i don't like it!

```
function order(rowName, array) {
    if (vm.row === rowName) {
        return;
    }

    vm.row = rowName;
    if (array === vm.itemsNew)
        vm.itemsNew = $filter('orderBy')(vm.itemsNew, rowName);
    else
        vm.itemsGeneric = $filter('orderBy')(vm.itemsGeneric, rowName);
    return vm.onOrderChange();
};
```

Comment: Can you add any fiddle/plnkr?

Comment: Is it even necessary to pass the array? Can `order` be called for other arrays too?

Comment: @zeroflagL Originally there was one array to be sorted, so there was no need for a second argument in the function.

But then a new one became necessary, so i just thought to pass a reference to the array i want to sort instead.

Comment: I don't know what's the point of returning the result of `vm.onOrderChange();`, but it should be possible to return `array` and have `data-ng-click = "vm.itemsNew = vm.order('amount', vm.itemsNew)"`

Comment: @zeroflagL That did the trick, thanks. The vm.onOrderChange(); just changes ta pagination page to 1, when the order changes. I just merged it with return to save a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-click` not only allows you to call a function but to evaluate arbitrary expressions. So you can return the filtered array from your function and assign it to the model:

```
data-ng-click = "vm.itemsNew = vm.order('amount', vm.itemsNew)"
```

The function:

```
...
array = $filter('orderBy')(array, rowName);
vm.onOrderChange();
return array;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line tries to change reference to `array` which is argument of the function.

```
array = $filter('orderBy')(array, rowName);
```

Simple answer is that you can't change original reference inside of the function. This is why `vm.itemsNew = $filter('orderBy')(vm.itemsNew, rowName);` working correctly.

You can read more here:
[Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Good thing is that you are seeing that your solution is very ugly ;)

You can use filter and rewrite array like this:

```
    function order(rowName, array) {
        if (vm.row === rowName) {
            return;
        }

        vm.row = rowName;
        var tmpArray = $filter('orderBy')(array, rowName);
        array.length = 0; //clears array
        angular.forEach(tmpArray, function(item) { // fill array with ordered values from tmpArray.
            array.push(item);
        });
        return vm.onOrderChange();
    };
```

Obviously, this is not the best from performance point of view. I **highly recommend** you to learn more about passing arguments to functions in JS. Link above is good starting point.